# In testing, how do I get an attribute using XPath?

Tags: testing

In Drupal BrowserTestBase, I am trying to access an attribute value using XPath:

```
$query = $this->xpath('//a[text() = "View"]/@data-drupal-link-system-path');
```

I can't figure out any way to get the actual value.

```
$path = $query[0]->value;
```

Results in error message:
`Undefined property: Behat\Mink\Element\NodeElement::$value`

```
$path = $query[0]->getValue();
```

Results in error message:
`Error: Call to undefined method DOMAttr::hasAttribute()`

```
$path = $query[0]->getAttribute('data-drupal-link-system-path');
```

Results in error message:
`Error: Call to undefined method DOMAttr::hasAttribute()`

The following works, but isn't the XPath I want to use:

```
$query = $this->xpath('//a[text() = "View"]');
$path = $query[0]->getAttribute('data-drupal-link-system-path');
```

Is there any way to get at the value of an attribute from an XPath attribute query?

Comment: Might be wrong but I think the answer is "no" - a `NodeElement` doesn't appear to have a way to behave like a `DOMAttr` would, so it appears attribute selectors aren't directly supported. You could use your last (working) example with the xpath changed to `$query = $this->xpath('//a[text() = "View"][@data-drupal-link-system-path]');` to get the same effect